# How do I release a pool connection from a model?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline, bluebird

I want to read a big JSON file ([this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SteveHodge/ed-systems/master/systems.json) to be precise), iterate over it, check which are new entries and save or update as necessary.

Doing this with sails, and sails mysql I found out that the whole process slows down the first time and if I try to run it a second time it dies at some point. My mysql server seems to handle that for around 24k requests and dies.

Here is the code with which I made it worked, but it completely ignores sails, or sails-mysql and I use mysql directly to achieve this.

This is the working code:

```
var path = require('path')
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'))
var rootPath = process.cwd()
var filePath = path.join(rootPath, 'assets/systems.json')
var mysql = require("mysql");
Promise.promisifyAll(mysql);
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Connection").prototype);
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Pool").prototype);
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
  database: 'db'
});

function getSqlConnection() {
  return pool.getConnectionAsync().disposer(function(connection) {
    connection.release();
  });
}

fs.readFileAsync(filePath, 'utf8').then(JSON.parse).then(function(systems) {
  total = systems.length
  return systems
})
.map(function(item, index, value) {
  Promise.using(getSqlConnection(), function (conn) {
    return conn.queryAsync('SELECT * FROM system WHERE name = "' + item.name + '"')
  })
  .then(function(have_system) {
    // do something with the info
    return the_result_of_doing_something
  })
  .caught(function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
}, {concurency: 5})
.caught(SyntaxError, function(e) {
  console.log("Invalid JSON in file " + e.fileName + ": " + e.message);
})
.lastly(function() {
  broadcast(["All DONE!!!", updated_systems, new_systems, current])
})
```

How can I achieve this without requiring mysql again and creating my own connection? So this:

```
function getSqlConnection() {
  return pool.getConnectionAsync().disposer(function(connection) {
    connection.release();
  });
}

Promise.using(getSqlConnection(), function (conn) {
  return conn.queryAsync('SELECT * FROM system WHERE name = "' + item.name + '"')
})
```

Would become something like:

```
function getSailsConnection() {
  return sails.pool.getConnectionAsync().disposer(function(connection) {
    connection.release();
  });
}

Promise.using(getSailsConnection(), function (conn) {
  return conn.System.findOne({name: item.name})
})
```

If I can properly release I don't even have to use Promise.using() since the waterline model can use promises.

```
System.findOne({name: item.name}).then(function(have_system) {
  // do something
  System.releaseConection() // or some other API call to achieve this
})
.caught(function(err) {
  System.releaseConection() // or some other API call to achieve this
})
```

PS: I tried to add a sails-mysql tag too but I'm not allowed.

Comment: Why not just overwrite the entire file every time? seems faster than checking for changed entries.

Comment: @AlexHill I don't want to write the file. I want to read from it and import it into the database. Then when I do have entries update the database instead of wiping it and import again. Also users could modify entries in the database which I want to compare with the file and submit pull requests to that repository with the added or corrected information.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning any promise from `.map` callback so not only will the promise fulfill prematurely, `concurrency` will not do anything.

You could also use a single connection for the whole thing:

```
using(getSailsConnection(),
      fs.readFileAsync(filePath, 'utf8').then(JSON.parse), function(conn, systems) {
    return systems.map(function(item) {
        return conn.System.findOne({name: item.name});
          .then(function() {

          })
    }, {concurrency: 5});
})
.lastly(function() {
  broadcast(["All DONE!!!", updated_systems, new_systems, current])
})
```

Comment: Isn't the return in the last then what is returned from the whole chain inside map?

Comment: @tic2000 return statement in javascript doesn't magically return something for other functions, only the function the return statement is in

Comment: OK. I added a return.

But unfortunately this doesn't answer my main question. How can I achieve this in sails, cause `conn.System.findOne({name: item.name})` doesn't work and I still have to use `conn.queryAsync('SELECT * FROM system WHERE name = "' + item.name + '"')`

Comment: @tic2000 you need to implement getSailsConnection

Comment: But how? That was my question. My getSailsConnection was pseudo code.

I don't know how to hook in the pool sails-mysql already created and get a connection from there.

Comment: @tic2000 does sails mysql have documentation?

Comment: @tic2000 I think you can just run `System.findOne` without having to create connection yourself